# Simplify $\cot(2\alpha)-\cot(\alpha)$ without using the double angle formula.

Tags: trigonometry, fractions

I tried to solve it by the following way: $$\frac{1}{\tan(\alpha+\alpha)}-\frac{1}{\tan(\alpha)}=\frac{-(1+\tan^2(\alpha))}{2\tan(\alpha)}=\frac{2\tan(\alpha)}{\cos^2(\alpha)}.$$ This answer is incorrect, because it must be $$-\frac{1}{\sin(2\alpha)}.$$ How can I solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't that last expression be $-1/(2\tan\alpha\cos^2\alpha)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If you mean the answer at the bottom, according to my book it should be as it is. I don't know, that could be wrong, maybe...

Comment: $\frac{-(1+\tan^2(\alpha))}{2\tan(\alpha)}=-\frac{1}{2\tan\alpha \cos^2\alpha}=-\frac{1}{2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}=-\frac{1}{\sin(2\alpha)}.$Here we use  $1+\tan^2\alpha=\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}$.

Comment: How is this not using the double angle foremula?

Comment: @stevengregory I think you meant "Isn't it the using of the double angle formula here at the end?" I was mistaken, by thinking that the double angle formula wouldn't be applied here as this question was included in the theme before the one on double angle formulae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{-(1+\tan^2(\alpha))}{2\tan(\alpha)}=-\frac{1}{2\tan\alpha \cos^2\alpha}=-\frac{1}{2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}=-\frac{1}{\sin(2\alpha)}.$$

Here we use  $$1+\tan^2\alpha=\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\cot2\alpha-\cot\alpha=\frac{\cos2\alpha\sin\alpha-\sin2\alpha\cos\alpha}{\sin2\alpha\sin\alpha}=$$
$$=\frac{-\sin\alpha}{\sin2\alpha\sin\alpha}=-\frac{1}{\sin2\alpha}$$

Comment: This is a more elegant looking solution, the way I would also do it (+1).